# How can I reopen a closed realm database after performing a backup?

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, realm

I am using a realm database with react native. I have a file realm.js where I am defining my realm schema and the path where the database shall be stored:

```
import Realm from 'realm';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'

class Test extends Realm.Object {}
Test.schema = {
    name: 'Test',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: {type: 'string', optional: false},
        ...,
    },
};

export default new Realm({schema: [Test],
                          path: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/t_db.realm"});
```

I am using this realm via import: `import realm from './realm'` and for example: `this.query = realm.objects('Test').sorted('id');`.

In my app I want to implement a backup function in which the realm db gets copied to the external user storage. Therefor I use React Native Filesystem with this function:

```
import realm from './realm'
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'

backup() {
  console.log("path ", realm.path)
  realm.close()
  console.log("closed ", realm.isClosed)
  RNFS.copyFile(realm.path, RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath + "/t_db.realm")
  console.log("copied")
  realm.open()
}
```

My console.logs suggest that I am successfully copying the database but I can not reopen it. Following error gets thrown at this point:

> ReactNativeJS: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_realm2.default.open()')

When I am trying to wait for the copy to be finished like so:

```
RNFS.copyFile(realm.path, RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath + "/t_db.realm")
.then(() => {
  console.log("copied")
  realm.open()
})
```

I get the following error after console.log("copied"):

> ReactNativeJS: 'Unhandled promise rejection', { [TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_realm2.default.open()')]

Can anyone help me how to resolve this?